# Python : Import modules once then share with several files

Tags: python, python-import

I have files as follow,

```
file1.py
file2.py
file3.py
```

Let's say that all three use

```
lib7.py
lib8.py
lib9.py
```

Currently each of the three files has the lines

```
import lib7
import lib8
import lib9
```

How can I setup my directory/code such that the libs are imported only once, and then shared among the three files?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834/can-someone-explain-all-in-python) and consider creating a single `mylib.py` file that imports all three libraries, then publishes the symbols you want via `__all__`.

Comment: In case you're worried about modules being imported multiple times in the same file,  Python loads the imported file into the namespace only once. Any subsequent imports of the same file will not be loaded.

Comment: @hhbilly Didn't know that, thanks! That was part of what I was worried about. The other was repetitive code.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You will have to import something at least once per file. But you can set it up such that this is a single import line:

The probably cleanest way is to create a folder `lib`, move all `lib?.py` in there, and add an empty file called `__init__.py` to it.

This way you create a [package](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages) out of your `lib?.py` files. It can then be used like this:

```
import lib
lib.lib7
```

---

Depending on where you want to end up, you might also want to have some code in the `__init__.py`:

```
from lib7 import *
from lib8 import *
from lib9 import *
```

This way you get all symbols from the individual `lib?.py` in a single `import lib`:

```
import lib
lib.something_from_lib7
```

Answer (score 9):

Import each of them in a separate module, and then import that:

`lib.py`:

```
import lib7
import lib8
import lib9
```

In each of the files (`file1.py`, `file2.py`, `file3.py`), just use `import lib`. Of course, you then have to reference them with `lib.lib7` – to avoid that, you can use `from lib import *`.