# How to write python code to be split into multiple files?

Tags: python, object, python-import

Currently I have a python file that goes like this (really simplified):

```
u = 30
colors = ('blue', 'red')
grid = [0, 1]

class entity:
    def __init___(self, x, color)
        self.x = x
        self.color = color

    def move(self):
        print(grid[self.x + 1], self.color)
        

foo = entity(0, 'blue')
bar = entity(0, 'red')
while true:
    foo.move()
    bar.move()
```

I tried to split it out and I got this:

```
# initialisation.py
u = 30
colors = ('blue', 'red')
```

```
# grid_map.py
from initialisation import u, colors
grid = [0, 1]
```

```
# classes.py
from map import u, colors, grid  # or *
class entity:
    def __init___(self, x, color)
        self.x = x
        self.color = color

    def move(self):
        print(grid[self.x + 1], self.color)
```

```
# objects.py
from classes import u, colors, grid, entity  # or *
foo = entity(0, 'blue')
bar = entity(0, 'red')
```

```
# main.py
from objects import u, colors, grid, entity, foo, bar  # or *
while true:
    foo.move()
    bar.move()
```

Now, I feel like I should be importing in a way that isn't this import-chain from one file to the next, but I'm unsure exactly how.

(hopefully this is a minimal, reproducible example)

Comment: Why are `u` and `colors` unused?

Comment: Seems like i minimized too much... Harder than it seems to ask a question perfectly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Importing as a chain isn't useful, except for very specific instances where a module adds or defines functionality on an imported object or class. Since you're not using `u`, `colors`, `grid` or `entity` in `main.py`, there is no reason to import them at all.

And *if* you need to import them, you import them from the file where *they are defined*, not from `objects`.

In `objects.py` you only need to import `entity` from `classes`, and in `classes` you only need `grid` from `map` (btw, `map` is a bad name, since it shadows the internal `map` function).

There is no need to import symbols you don't use - you don't have to think about what the module you're importing needs; the module is responsible for that by itself.

(Another small nitpick; class names should have TitleCase, so `Entity` would be the correct capitalization (I'd also suggest a better class name, since `Entity` doesn't really say much)) (and it's `True`, not `true`).

Comment: Seems I minimized too much. In the original code there's more in each file. As a result if I only import whats in a specific file, there's a module imported once per file, and u and colors being imported in two files. Is that duplicate importation bad or alright?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37403816/14030287 the comment in the question "answered" my question and your answer directed me to that question.

Comment: It's perfectly fine; just to make sure; "will not be loaded" in the comment refers to the file being loaded from disk, the module's content will be available as expected.